# How SELECT Product from Same Supplier, Get this ERROR Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, select

im New in this query world.
I Try to SELECT a products column [vProducto] from the same Supplier [vProveedor] from a table [mod_productos] but i get error [Subquery returns more than 1 row]

Im trying with this code:

```
SELECT vProducto 
FROM mod_productos 
WHERE vProducto IN (
    SELECT vProducto 
    FROM mod_productos  
    WHERE vProveedor="Telefonica"
);
```

Any help on how to do this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for comment @Strawberry

Comment: Thanks you @Saša Ćetković

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    vProducto 
FROM mod_productos 
WHERE 
    vProducto IN (
        SELECT vProducto FROM mod_productos WHERE vProveedor="Telefonica"
    );
```

The above query is fine and you should not be getting the "Subquery returns more than one row" exception with your syntax here.

When you run into the more than one row exception, it's typically a result of using a SELECT subquery as a column.

For example

```
SELECT
   pkMyProdID
   , ( SELECT field FROM OtherTable WHERE fkMyProdID = pkMyProdID ) AS SubQueryColumn
FROM myTable;
```

In this example only one row can be returned for "SubQueryColumn" otherwise you end up with the more than one row error.

While I **would not** recommend doing it this way ( are you expecting more than one row? ), you can get around this by modifying my above example to:

```
SELECT
   pkMyProdID
   , ( SELECT TOP 1 field FROM OtherTable WHERE fkMyProdID = pkMyProdID ) AS SubQueryColumn
FROM myTable;
```

Notice the "TOP 1" that I added to the subquery. This ensures only one row will be returned--but--know your data. If you're not expecting more than one row but you're receiving it, look into why.

Comment: "Notice the "TOP 1" that I added to the subquery. This ensures only one row will be returned-" No it ensures you get a SQL error in MySQL, MySQL uses `LIMIT 1`.. Besides SQL is a **unsorted** set off data i assume SQL server which does support `TOP` should do it in combination with `ORDER BY`.. Otherwise the DMBS (or anny DMBS which is using a record limiting clause) will **not guarantee** to get the same record(s) when running the same query twice or multiple times.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea this was for MySql. That would have helped.

Comment: Hi @Critical Error , thank you very much for sharing your explanation and great knowledge. I need to display All the products not just one. I try your query but i get this error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: What database are you using?